# labview python integration toolkit error91

Tags: python, labview, enthought

I'm trying to process a two-dimensional array by using the python integration toolkit,
The data expelled by unpacking is an invalid value, and it cannot be outputted even if the conversion from variant to data function is used.
It is error91.

What can be thought of as the cause of becoming an invalid value?

Processing in the function is done by converting to pandas DataFrame, but the return value is returned as an array of numpy. (I use .values)

[image]

Comment: I do not know anything about that toolkit (that's the one made by Enthought, right?). If you cannot get the problem fixed, LabVIEW 2018 added python integration as a native language feature. Might be worth trying.

Comment: Yes, it is enthought's toolkit.

I do not think it is a language problem, because for a simple program I could use toolkit successfully. (It is a program that returns the square of the elements of an array.)

Comment: Please email this question (including this VI screenshot) to support@enthought.com

Comment: You can also try Wineman's new Python/LabVIEW Connector: TestScript.